# Fail to solve E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android

When back to previous activity or I get out the app is closed and show this error:

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Within a asycntask in his method onPostExecute I declare a recycleview and           RecyclerView.LayoutManager but no have idea what it's wrong. I need your help to solve this problem. Below is my code:

```
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(List<Modules> result) {

        if (pDialog.isShowing()){

       RecyclerView.LayoutManager  Manager =new LinearLayoutManager(DepartureModule.this);

            RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new ModuleAdapter(result);

            RecyclerView RVODetails = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RVODetails);
            RVODetails.setLayoutManager(Manager);

            RVODetails.setAdapter(adapter);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

and this is my adapter class:

```
public  class ModuleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    public final ImageButton Actions;
    public final ImageView Image;
    public final  TextView ModuleCode;
    public final  TextView ModuleDescription;
    public final  TextView ModuleDate;
    public String ModuleIds;

    public ModuleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        Actions = (ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Actions);
        //TitleModuleCode = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.TitleModuleCode);
        ModuleCode = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ModuleCode);
        //TitleModuleDescription = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.TitleModuleDescription);
        ModuleDescription  = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ModuleDescription);
        ModuleDate  = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ModuleDate);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        this.itemClickListener.OnItemClick(view,getLayoutPosition());
        // Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "POS" + getLayoutPosition()
        // , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener ItemClick){
        this.itemClickListener = ItemClick;
    }
}

public ModuleAdapter(List<Modules> Items){
    this.Items = Items;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Items.size();
}

@Override
public ModuleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_cardview,viewGroup,false);
    return new ModuleViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ModuleViewHolder ViewHolder, final int position) {

    context = ViewHolder.itemView.getContext();

    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "fonts/CaviarDreams.ttf");        

    ViewHolder.Image.setImageResource(Items.get(position).getImages());

    ViewHolder.Actions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ShowPopupMenu(ViewHolder.Actions,position,ViewHolder);
        }
    });

    ViewHolder.ModuleCode.setText(Items.get(position).getModule()); 
    ViewHolder.ModuleCode.setTypeface(typeface);         ViewHolder.ModuleDescription.setText(Items.get(position).getDescription());

    ViewHolder.ModuleDescription.setTypeface(typeface);       
    ViewHolder.ModuleDate.setText(Items.get(position).getDate());    
    ViewHolder.ModuleDate.setTypeface(typeface);

    ViewHolder.ModuleIds = Items.get(position).getModuleIds();

    ViewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnItemClick(View view, int Pos) {
            //Toast.makeText(context, "POSITION :" + Pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void ShowPopupMenu (final View view, final int position,final ModuleViewHolder holder){

    menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.action_modify:

                    final Connection connectionupdate = new Connection(context,Connection.DATABASE_NAME,null,
                            Connection.DATABASE_VERSION);          
                    final SQLiteDatabase dbUpdate = connectionupdate.getWritableDatabase();

                    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/CaviarDreams.ttf");
                    AlertDialog.Builder ModifyModule = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                    LayoutInflater modifyinflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
                            (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    final View viewmodify = modifyinflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_custom_dialog_create_modules,null);

                    TILM  = (TextInputLayout)viewmodify.findViewById(R.id.TILM);
                    TILM.setTypeface(typeface);
                    TILD  = (TextInputLayout)viewmodify.findViewById(R.id.TILD);
                    TILD.setTypeface(typeface);
                    ModuleCodeE  = (EditText)viewmodify.findViewById(R.id.ModuleCode);
                    ModuleCodeE.setTypeface(typeface);
                    ModuleDescE  = (EditText)viewmodify.findViewById(R.id.ModuleDesc);
                    ModuleDescE.setTypeface(typeface);

                    ModuleCodeE.setText(Items.get(position).getModule());
                    ModuleDescE.setText(Items.get(position).getDescription());
                    final String Id = Items.get(position).getModuleIds();

                    ModifyModule.setView(viewmodify);
                    ModifyModule.setIcon(R.drawable.logomini);

                    ModifyModule.setTitle("Construmuebles FM");
                    ModifyModule.setMessage(" Modifica los valores en los siguientes campos :");
                    ModifyModule.setPositiveButton("Actualizar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            ContentValues VUpdate = new ContentValues();

                            VUpdate.put(Database.CamposModuloDetails.KEY_MODULE_CODE,ModuleCodeE.getText().toString());                                VUpdate.put(Database.CamposModuloDetails.KEY_MODULE_DESC,ModuleDescE.getText().toString());

                            long IdUpdate = dbUpdate.update(Database.MODULE_DETAILS_TABLE,VUpdate,Database.CamposModuloDetails
                                    .KEY_MODULE_DETAILS_ID + " = ?",new String []{Id});

                            new UpdateCardView(context,IdUpdate).execute();

                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    ModifyModule.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface
                            .OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    ModifyModule.show();

                    return true;

                case R.id.action_delete:

                    new  DeleteCardView(context,holder,position).execute();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    menu.show();
}

class DeleteCardView extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Long>{
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ModuleViewHolder holder;
    int position;

    public DeleteCardView(Context context,ModuleViewHolder holder,int position) {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        this.holder = holder;
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog.setMessage(" Eliminado registro...");
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        String ModuleIdCardView = holder.ModuleIds;
        Connection connection = new Connection(context, Connection.DATABASE_NAME, null,
                Connection.DATABASE_VERSION);
        long i = connection.DeleteByIdCardView(ModuleIdCardView);
        if (i != 0) {
            return i;
        } else {
            return i;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long Result) {
        if (pDialog.isShowing()){
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Items.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position,Items.size());
            if (Items.size()==0){ /**viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);**/ }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rearrange your code as follows

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RVODetails);

    mAdapter = new ModuleAdapter(result);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Rubin But I rearrange my code as you indicated and that problem still persists,There is another reason as to why only the application is closed and now ?

Comment: my recycleview is displayed into a viewpager in your second page  when entering the activity that contains the viewpager throws me a message

Comment: dear friend and could resolve my problem was a badly written code that had one of the pages of ViewPager